# How to get more debugging info from Java calling native C code

Tags: java, c, debugging, java-native-interface

I'm no Java programmer but I wrote (and tested) a C library called from Java JNI/Swig. Lately it crashes when called from Java and it used to work fine. I'm struggling to find any meaningful info about the crashes.
I get a hs_err_pid153408.log file with tons (1100 lines) of useless content in it.

Inside it says a core file was generated, but that is not true. So is there a way to get Java to save a core file I can then look through with gdb ?

```
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h" (or dumping to //core.153408)
```

Then in that log file the only reference to the C code is this:

```
# C  [libc.so.6+0x19557c]  __strlen_evex+0x1c
```

But that's no help. How can I get a complete backtrace of the C code, not just the Java ? Yes, I compile with debugging options ON.
Thanks

Comment: did you try running `ulimit -c unlimited` before starting your Java program? That might cause it to generate a core file. It says your core dumps are processed with systemd-coredump - did you check in the folder /var/lib/systemd/coredump where they are apparently saved?

Comment: It's not started manually but by some server process. Is there a global setting for ulimit ?

Comment: with systemd-coredumpd there are [configuration files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/coredump.conf.html)

Comment: Set your logging level to debug and read the logs your code emits when the logging level is set that high?

Comment: Now `systemd` has taken over core dumps too?!? Well, I found the dumps in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` where even `updatedb` wouldn't. But they are zst files and I haven't been able to get a backtrace with source lines yet.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to invoke `coredumpctl debug` to launch `gdb` with the latest core dump (there are other options).

Like @user253751 said, you may have to increase the dump size in `/etc/systemd/coredump.conf`